# Youtube upload api duplicated video (get the right ID)

Tags: youtube-api

When a video is duplicated (let's say v = GgVH5fXXYSE) , is there a way i can find the videoid of the "good" one (the one that should work) with the duplicated id.
(so with GgVH5fXXYSE i could find eNqZgEgOfsw)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get this information. It's come up as a feature request a number of times in the past, and there are technical reasons why this can't be exposed in the YouTube Data API response.

Comment: Can the API return a duplicate status or something similar that will tell us the upload was flagged as a duplicate? Also, I am using the dotnet client so would be helpful if the `Video` class includes a property that will indicate the uploaded video is a duplicate.

Comment: `duplicate` is one of the values that are returned in the `reasonCode` of the `yt:state` tag: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:state

Comment: Yes I understand but thanks for reminding me as I see I have not included it as part of the request and so I get nothing (null). The status is not returned though, using the dotnet client. But I think I need to create a new thread for that issue, will do that. Thanks again @JeffPosnick

Answer (score 0):

If you have APP, that solely uploads file to particular (authorized) youtube account(s), then you can get it done using following method. Maintain a hash of all input files and while uploading file, check ,if you have old file having same hash as current file upload, and that old file was uploaded successfully, then don't upload that file and use youtube link = old file's ( having same hash as current file) youtube link.